# How does Heat flows in Carnot engine?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

According to fundamental concept of thermal conduction, heat flows from higher temperature to lower temperature. As in Carnot cycle, there is isothermal expansion and compression as a process i.e. Temperature is constant. So how does heat is flowing from source to system or system to sink in Carnot cycle if Temperature is constant? If we consider that some how heat is flowing then why does Temperature is constant as by 1st law **△Q= △U + W** heat given should increase internal energy i.e. temperature increase of system?

Please do not downvote as it discourages me to post any question.

Comment: A great textbook will tell you that it is really just about how small you can make the temperature difference. The deviations from Carnot would then be negligible if, for a heat source at $T_H+\delta$, only goes as $\delta^2$ (or sums over time to only $\delta$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Carnot cycle is an idealized thermodynamic cycle that provides an upper limit on the efficiency of any classical thermodynamic engine during the conversion of heat into work. It consists of four stages: two isothermal (constant temperature) processes and two adiabatic (no heat transfer) processes.

As for the first law of thermodynamics (ΔQ = ΔU + W), it still holds in each step of the Carnot cycle. In the isothermal steps, the work done by or on the system is exactly equal to the heat absorbed or released, so the internal energy (and therefore the temperature) remains constant.

In the Carnot cycle, heat transfer occurs during the isothermal processes. Here’s how:

Isothermal Expansion: The system (a gas, for example) is in thermal contact with a high-temperature reservoir (source). The system absorbs heat from the source, which causes it to expand. Even though the system absorbs heat, its temperature remains constant because the absorbed heat is used to do work (expansion against external pressure). This is possible because the process is carried out very slowly, allowing the system to remain in equilibrium.

Isothermal Compression: The system is in contact with a low-temperature reservoir (sink). It is compressed, causing it to release heat to the sink. Again, the temperature remains constant during this process.

I hope this answers your question. If not, please comment your doubts and I'll edit it accordingly!

Comment: So your answer clears my doubt of why the temperature is constant even if the heat is flowing, but now also my first doubt is unclear how the heat is flowing even if the temperature between the source and the system is the same or the temperature between the sink and the system is same, contradicting the fundamental law of thermal conductivity( Heat flows from higher temp to lower temp).

Comment: The fundamental law that you are referring to is when every other state variable is considered constant. Here, there is work being done which is the main reason why the heat is flowing. (It makes more sense if you think it using Law of Conservation of Energy which basically is the First Law)